# Extract text and image from a pdf in a selected area or coordinates

Tags: asp.net, pdf, acrobat

I have a specific requirement of extracting text and images from a specific area in a pdf file.The area might be a selected or highlighted or from a given set of coordinates.

When i went through, all the approaches are to extract images and text entirely from the PDF on not in a specified location. 
I tried with iTextSharp,Syncfussion,Apose but couldn figure out a better approach for this.

If somebody could help me out in this it would be greatfull. Can you share your ideas and suggestion on how to implement this in .net.

Regards,
Arun.M

Answer (score 1):

this code  extract images from pdf

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using Bytescout.PDFExtractor;

namespace ExtractAllImages
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // This test file will be copied to the project directory on the pre-build event (see the project properties).
            String inputFile = Server.MapPath("sample1.pdf");

            // Create Bytescout.PDFExtractor.ImageExtractor instance
            ImageExtractor extractor = new ImageExtractor();
            extractor.RegistrationName = "demo";
            extractor.RegistrationKey = "demo";

            // Load sample PDF document
            extractor.LoadDocumentFromFile("sample1.pdf");

            Response.Clear();

            int i = 0;

            // Initialize image enumeration
            if (extractor.GetFirstImage())
            {
                do
                {
                    if (i == 0) // Write the fist image to the Response stream
                    {
                        string imageFileName = "image" + i + ".png";

                        Response.Write("<b>" + imageFileName + "</b>");

                        Response.ContentType = "image/png";
                        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + imageFileName);

                        // Write the image bytes into the Response output stream
                        Response.BinaryWrite(extractor.GetCurrentImageAsArrayOfBytes());
                    }

                    i++;

                } while (extractor.GetNextImage()); // Advance image enumeration
            }

            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```